# Can't connect to wireless network ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I am having trouble connecting to my wireless network after reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I used to dual boot 12.04 and windows on this computer and I had no problems with my wireless at that point. My wireless problem started when I removed windows and attempted a fresh install of 12.04 by itself.

Other info:

- My wired connection is fine
- I can establish a wireless connection when booting from a usb but not from my hard drive install.

Thanks

Comment: see if this can help http://linuxplained.com/how-to-fix-wireless-problems-in-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for **"linux-backports-modules-wireless"** in the Ubuntu Software Installer and make sure you select the correct version that matches your OS kernel version by typing "**uname -r**" on the terminal

f you are still experiencing wireless problems after installing the modules, follow the link below and install the drivers...the site holds instructions on how to do the installation

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/